# VIX-Model in Python

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

I read a paper about a model that uses signals of the Standard Deviation of the VIX Index.
I first tested the model in Excel and now I want to transform the model in Python code. I'm not that advanced yet in Python and got stuck.
The model is simple. Calculate the rolling 20-day standard deviation of the VIX closing prices. Signals are generated if the Standard Deviation is below 0.86 AND the prior 10 days did not generate a signal. So, calculating the 0.86 threshold is easy but how do I include the piece that no signal occurred the prior 10 days.

```
vix['std_dev'] = vix['CLOSE'].rolling(window=20).std()

vix['signal'] = np.where(vix['std_dev'] <= 0.86,1,0)
```

vix is just the data of OHLC prices for the VIX index.
I would suggest working with `.shift()`?

Comment: See https://github.com/meixler/vix for a python script that script that calculates the [CBOE Volatility Index (VIX)](https://markets.cboe.com/tradable_products/vix/) according to the method described in the [CBOE VIX White Paper](https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/futures/vixwhite.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create another rolling 10 day indication for the signal and use this result as a condition for the actual signal.